# How to connect/perform queries to Microsoft SQL on XCode

Tags: sql-server, xcode

I am new to programming, sorry. I am not so familiar with how everything goes.

I have this Iphone (Xcode) project:

They have setup a Microsoft SQL database. What I need to do is to connect to the database and perform queries on it through xcode.

I have seen articles on JSON,PHP,MySQL and other stuff but I really find it hard to understand.

Thanks for your help in advance! ^^

Answer (score 0):

I use the following:

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT serialNumber, catalogNumber FROM inventory WHERE partName=\"%@\"", partName.text];
```